# How can i get context parameter value in jsp.?

Tags: java, jsp

```
  <context-param>
        <param-name>productSearchRPP</param-name>
        <param-value>8</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

I want to get value of productSearchRPP in products.jsp page

Comment: request.getIntiParameter('key')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even you can try this in your jsp.

```
ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
com = context.getInitParameter("com");
```

and with jstl you can use.

```
${initParam['theStringIWant']}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
pageContext.getServletContext().getInitParameter("key");
```

This is how you get context parameter value in JSP.
In JSTL you can get it like this

```
${pageContext.servletContext}
```

Or

```
${applicationScope.attributeName}
```

Comment: i want to get it using jstl.

Comment: That first line should start with `pageContext` (note the capital 'C').  I tried editing the answer but stackoverflow says edits must be at least 6 characters long.

Comment: You mean expression language, not jstl?

Answer (score 9):

```
${initParam['productSearchRPP']}
```

Or, to  get inside scriptlet

```
<%= pageContext.getServletContext().getInitParameter("productSearchRPP") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
application.getInitParameter("productSearchRPP")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 application.getServletContext().getInitParameter("productSearchRPP");
```

use this to get required result