# JSP Tag Handler accessing context parameters

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller, jstl

I'm trying to retrieve values from my context parameters in the web.xml file from my Tag Handler class.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>driver</param-name>
    <param-value>driver value</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I'm accessing the parameter using..

```
String driver = ((PageContext) getJspContext()).getServletConfig().getInitParameter("driver");
```

It only ever returns null... is there something I'm missing? I know that you have to cast the JspContext to PageContext to work with the config methods, so I don't know where I'm going wrong. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you retrieve the value in JSP page use pageContext variable directly.
Use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039220/how-can-i-get-context-parameter-value-in-jsp)

If you want retrieve the value in JSP page then use

> pageContext.getServletContext().getInitParameter("driver");

If you want to retrieve inside servlet then use

> getServletContext().getInitParameter("driver");

If you want to do it using TagHandler use below code snippet:

```
PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();
String driver = request.getSession().getServletContext().
    getInitParameter("driver");
```

Please read [this](https://coderanch.com/t/288223/java/Accessing-webapp-context-parameters-custom)

Comment: Yep that worked perfectly. I had actually read that before asking here, but didn't think I had to use requests since it will be called within my index and I wasn't sending anything. I understand it now. Thanks for your help @SachinSarawgi