# getting param-value from jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to get the value of a param in **web.xml**

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
```

from jsp page

Comment: suppose this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039220/how-can-i-get-context-parameter-value-in-jsp) address the same issue you are facing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get context parameter value in jsp.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039220/how-can-i-get-context-parameter-value-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Do this.`pageContext.getServletContext().getInitParameter("key");`

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.